# How to omit confirmButton &cancelButton from SystemDialog in c++ for Q10?

Tags: c++, user-interface, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am facing a strange problem regarding SystemDialog. I need to omit confirmButton & cancelButton from my dialog. And I put the following code to do so-

```
SystemUiButton *cancelButton = alertDialog->cancelButton();
cancelButton->setLabel(QString::null);
SystemUiButton *confirmButton = alertDialog->confirmButton();
confirmButton->setLabel(QString::null);
```

It's perfectly working in Z10. But in Q10 it's not working. My both device running on 10.1
Can you guys please put some feedback regarding this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue on 10.2 recently and it appears in 10.2 it just disabled the buttons and does not remove them.  It looks like it's easier to just create a custom dialog instead of using the default systemdialog.  You might have slightly different builds of 10.1 between your two devices which is why one works and the other doesn't.